# Pro ASP.Net MVC 3 Entity Framework Sports Store tutorial

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Following the tutorial in the book "Pro ASP.Net MVC 3 Entity Framework" in Chapter 9 - Image Uploads section; asks that the `Product` class be updated with two new columns - public byte `ImageData`, and public string `ImageType`. It also directs that the database be updated with these two columns via the server explorer.

After these updates, the discussion directs that the Entity Framework Conceptual Model be updated via the `SportsStore.EDMX` file. This file does not exist in the source code for the project, and was not used in the project to begin with. Obvious errata for the book.

Adding the ADO.NET Entity Data Model to the Project then overrides the EFProduct reposistory (conceptual model used throughout the project) which inherits from the interface `IProductsRepository`; and results in errors within the mapping.

If the project is debugged after the columns are added, an error is thrown related to the new added columns.

Has anyone resolved this issue in the project? I haven't found any solutions so far.

Comment: I remember reading and coming across exactly the same problem.  From memory you should be able to remove the edmx, rebuild and make sure there are no errors.  You should be able to carry on without it since it does utilise the EF Code First model - you just need to confirm the database structure and POCOs match.  If not I will see if I can find my code!

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, Bo. Actually the edmx file doesn't exist in the project, and adding it creates mapping problems. Without it there are several errors with the ef files needing to be resolved - which I'm working on. If you do have some direction for code that would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have discovered that the Product Class property ImageData is missing the the array [] brackets. It should read: public byte[] Imagedata { get; set; }

This handles the runtime errors related to using a null value for the ImageData byte data type while working on the book exercise.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add ImageData and ImageMimeType into Products table, then set all of the values as empty string. it should make the sample application work.